# AS3 unloading SWF from loaded SWF itself

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I've been messing with my AS3 codes trying to find a way to get a loaded swf unloaded by pressing te close_btn which is in the loaded SWF.
I can't seem to get that to work, so Maybe you guys know a way to do this.

so:

main_swf loads swf_1.

And in swf_1 is the close_btn which should unload swf_1.

So that we get back to main_swf.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a following function in main_swf:

```
private function killSWF1():void{
    _loader.unloadAndStop();
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop%28%29

and then pass it into the loaded swf:

```
private function onInit(e:Event):void{
    _mc = loader.content as MovieClip;
    _mc['toCall'] = killSWF1;
    addChild(_mc);
}
```

and in the loaded swf you'll have just to call it: `toCall()`

Answer (score 0):

`main_swf` has a `loader` which loads your `swf_1`.

my suggestion would be:
If `close_btn` is on the main stage of the `swf_1`. When a `close_btn` gets clicked:

```
function handleClose ( e : MouseEvent ) : void
{
    // this needs to be in the root section of the swf_1
    this.dispatchEvent ( new Event ( Event.CLOSE ) );
}
```

inside the `main_swf` after the `swf_1` has been loaded:

```
loader.content.addEventListener ( Event.CLOSE, handleContentClosed );

function handleContentClosed ( e : Event ) : void
{
    // removing the event listener, making the content ready for GC
    loader.content.removeEventListener( Event.CLOSE, handleContentClosed );
    // removing the actual content from the place it was added
    removeChild ( loader.content );
    // unloading and stoppping the loaded swf
    loader.unloadAndStop ();
}
```

more info about [unloadAndStop()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop%28%29)